# Convert command from c# to powershell

Tags: powershell

Can you please help me converting the below C# to PowerShell

```
        byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
```

Below is the full code what I am trying to do here.
I am trying to generate a hash code here

```
 Function CalculateHashWithSalt($input = "Password@123", $salt="qLTf99m__JGu", $algorithmName = "SHA512")
    {


       $pass = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8


       $input = "Password123"
       $data1 = $pass.GetBytes($input)

       $saltbytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
       $saltbytes=$saltbytes.GetBytes($salt)

        $plainTextWithSaltBytes=@()
        $plainTextWithSaltBytes = $data1.Length + $saltbytes.Length



        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data1.Length; $i++)
        {
            $plainTextWithSaltBytes[$i] = $data1[$i]
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $saltbytes.Length; $i++)
        {
            $plainTextWithSaltBytes[$pass.Length + $i] = $saltbytes[$i];
        }

        [System.Byte[]]::new($hashBytes)
        $hashBytes = $algorithmName.ComputeHash($plainTextWithSaltBytes);


        $Encrypted = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($hashBytes)

    }
```

Trying to convert the below c# code :
[C# code link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/viewCodeSnippet.jsp?codeSnippetId=7939959)

Comment: PowerShell's arrays concatenate much more conveniently: you can just do `$plainTextWithSaltBytes = $data1 + $saltbytes` to get the whole thing at once with no requirement to alloc a new array and copy stuff. If the arrays are very large, an intermediate step with `[Buffer]::BlockCopy` may be necessary, but I doubt that's the case.

Comment: ya but i am doing the following after this which is giving me error...
`            `for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data1.Length; $i++)
            {
                $plainTextWithSaltBytes[$i] = $data1[$i]
            }`

Comment: It looks like in the C# code, you want to instantiate a new byte array having the sizes of `plainTextBytes` and `saltBytes` combined. So just the length is what counts, no? In that case you can do `$bytes = [System.Byte[]]::new($plainTextBytes.Length + $saltbytes.Length)`. If what you want is not a new array of '0' bytes, but the actual contents of `plainTextBytes` and `saltBytes` in there, use what  @JeroenMostert wrote

Comment: @Jeroen it worked that way...Thanks

Comment: As an aside: avoid the use of `$Input` as a [parameter] variable, because it is an automatic variable used by PowerShell (it enumerates pipeline / stdin input).

Answer (score 0):

From https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luc/2011/01/21/powershell-getting-the-hash-value-for-a-string/

I have this function in my personal scripts with a parameter for which algo to use.

```
function Hash($textToHash)
{
    $hasher = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed
    $toHash = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($textToHash)
    $hashByteArray = $hasher.ComputeHash($toHash)
    foreach($byte in $hashByteArray)
    {
         $res += $byte.ToString()
    }
    return $res;
}
```